# Case of moving longitudinal light clock with no time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

I refer here to the case of a light clock where each light pulse emitted travels forth and then reflected back between the two plates of the clock on the same axis as the direction of the moving clock:

[image: clock]

image credits: https://www.ajuronline.org/uploads/Volume%209/Issue%202%263/92.3D-FixelleArt.pdf

Assuming you are using very short duration light pulses much shorter in duration than the time it takes them to travel to the opposite plate in the case where the clock was stationary, then when the clock is on the move and you **register only** the pulse moving in the same direction with the clock when it reaches the opposite plate, the result will be time dilation for the time recorded by this clock.

However my question is, if you register the time instead, **only by using the reflected light pulse** coming back to the initial plate, then will there be any time dilation effect?

Comment: Certainly there will be time dilation, but you need to be careful in this case because it gets mixed up with length contraction and relativity-of-simultaneity effects. That's why pedagogically people usually start with the transverse light clock.

Comment: My controversial take on the whole situation is that in the case of short duration light pulses and measuring the two-way path, the LLC operates under Galilean relativity and not SR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time dilation formula in SR is a special case, and applies only to intervals between pairs of events that occur in the same place in one of the two frames being considered. For that reason, neither the outbound leg nor the return leg of the light pulse's journey will by itself give you the time dilation effect described by the equation. Indeed, what you will find is that in the non-clock frame the outbound leg will be longer than the return leg.

Comment: I found this related Arxiv paper https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1103/1103.0445.pdf

Comment: The paper contains mistakes. The second principle of relativity dos not say that it is impossible to detect motion, but that it is impossible to detect absolute motion.

Comment: Referring to the above previous comment Arxiv paper after reading it I found that this is a very strange special case where when the light pulse is  very short in duration and not a continuous wave therefore there is no Doppler shift observed, then the two-way speed symmetry postulate of light is broken and can be restored only if length dilation is assumed which is an impossibility in SR.

Comment: "The paper contains mistakes..." Yes I agree because his findings are very strange like "length dilation".

Comment: IMO in the described case of the moving clock registering only as a clock tick when the reflected short light pulse hits the trailing clock leg (where the pulsed light source is located), the number of clock ticks counted after the moving clock stops moving will be the same with that of a synchronized stationary reference light clock. Thus, there will be no overall time dilation effect for the stationary observer. But then this is unacceptable in SR since there can be no preferred frame of reference.

Comment: I don't understand what point you are trying to make. The case for SR is rock solid. The paper you cited was not peer reviewed, talks nonsense, and has gained no serious interest since it was published. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The number of ticks is always the same in every frame. What counts is the duration of the ticks.

Comment: In the transverse light clock I am not so sure if this the case. Running the experiment say for 15 minutes for the stationary reference clock and immediately bringing to stationary the moving clock because time dilation the moving clock will have less number of ticks registered.  But yes repeating this process for the longitudinal light clock the number of ticks recorded will be the same.

Comment: @Markoul11 if my transverse clock ticks n times in my frame it will also have ticked n times in yours. If my LLC ticks n times in my frame it will also tick n times in yours. Your theory about LLCs not conforming to SR is unjustified and incorrect.

Comment: @Markoul11 Where specifically in the paper that you reference does it say "length dilation"? (I could not find it.)

Comment: @Markoul11 In the Doppler effect, it's not necessary to see the color of light vary... it's sufficient to measure the ratio of the periods between consecutive receptions and consecutive emissions. So, using a sequence of "[short-lived] light pulses" is sufficient.

Comment: @robphy "...also the length of the longitudinal light clock must dilate at the same manner" last paragraph before the References. https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1103/1103.0445.pdf

Comment: @Markoul11 thanks.